# Is there a way to prioritize and send logs to elasticsearch inorder to optimize the log load on the server

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash, elastic-stack, nxlog

Need to read critical, error and warning in all application logs in my environment. If a critical happens after 1000 warnings, I want the Logstash to send it right away, giving priority order highest for critical, then for error and least for the warnings generated.

What are the options available here and How can it be done?

- Is there an inbuilt feature in Logstash for it?
- Is there another integration that can help achieve it? What about RabbitMQ? Can RabbitMQ directly send it to elastic search without Logstash?
- Is there another module of elastic or any other software that can be integrated to elastic search to achieve this end goal?

Preference for lightweight and fast solution.

I tried optimizing Logstash. Heard About RabbitMQ (Like to try it)

Answer (score 1):

**Logstash** itself doesn't have built-in prioritization to send the logs. Basically, it works like first in first out.

**RabbitMQ** can be used as a message broker to decouple log producers from log consumers. You can send logs to RabbitMQ and then consume and process them based on their severity.

**Kafka** acts as a distributed message broker. It can handle large volumes of logs and provides fault tolerance. You can create Kafka topics for each severity level to maintain separation.

**Kafka vs. RabbitMQ:**
Both Kafka and RabbitMQ are message brokers, but Kafka is often chosen for its durability, fault tolerance, and support for high-throughput scenarios.
RabbitMQ, on the other hand, might be simpler to set up initially and may be preferred in scenarios where guaranteed message delivery is critical.

[image]

Sample Logstash conf for [rabbitmq input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-rabbitmq.html) and [elasticsearch output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html):

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    id => "input_rabbitmq"
    exchange => "logstash-exchange"
    threads => 2
  }
}
filter {}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        data_stream => "true"
    }
}
```

Question: `filebeat => Logstash => Elasticsearch` data pipeline sends the document near-real time. Are you experiencing any delay between the log generation and indexing?

Comment: Not delay in log generation and indexing. But sometimes too much warning comes, resulting in delay of critical.

Comment: It makes sense to use a MESSAGE QUEUE to handle the sudden load. And you can definitely configure the priority of the queue with the above suggestions.

Comment: Recently I heard about Nxlogs. What about using it? From what I hear it can replace whole beats, RabbitMQ and Logstash from the above architecture. In their website, they say it can be connected to Elasticsearch - [KEN stack (Kibana, Elasticsearch, and NXLog)](https://docs.nxlog.co/integrate/elasticsearch-kibana.html).

Comment: I didn't heard about NxLogs before. I prefer to use a software that has strong community so RabbitMQ and/or Kafka would be best solution from my perspective.